# Calculate $\frac{\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(1-t^4)^{1/2}}}{\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(1+t^4)^{1/2}}}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Calculate $$\frac{\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(1-t^4)^{1/2}}}{\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(1+t^4)^{1/2}}}.$$

Changing element is likely to be a wise idea, but I have tried several times in vain.

Comment: It appears to be $\sqrt{2}$ but neither of these integrals have an elementary antiderivative so you'll have to write the numerator integral in terms of the the denominator.

Comment: Why the tag `indefinite-integrals`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the numerator and the denominator are complete elliptic integrals of the first kind. By enforcing the substitution $t\mapsto\sqrt{\cos\theta}$ in the numerator and the substitution $t\mapsto\sqrt{\tan\theta}$ in the denominator we are left with

$$\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{2\sqrt{\cos\theta}}\right)/\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{d\theta}{2\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}}\right)$$
or

$$\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{2\sqrt{\sin\theta}}\right)/\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{d\theta}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)}}\right)$$
which is clearly $\sqrt{2}$ by the sine duplication formula and the substitution $\theta\mapsto\frac{\varphi}{2}$ in the last integral.